# Backbone Router not working for direct access

Tags: backbone.js

My backbone router works fine if you click a link but doesn't work when trying to access a URL directly or if you refresh the page.

Router

```
var app = app || {};

var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "blog": "blog",
        "blog/post/:id": "blogPost",
        "faqs": "faqs",
        "*other": "defaultRoute"
    }
});

app.Router = new appRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

App

```
var app = app || {};

var view = new app.AppView();

app.Router.on('route:defaultRoute', function() {
    console.log("Default Route");
}

app.Router.on('route:blog', function() {
    console.log("Blog Route");
    view.showBlog();
}
```

I log to the console whenever a route is fired, but when you access a url directly or when refreshing the page no route is fired, not even the default route.

Comment: How did you access a url? With `#` symbol or not?

Comment: with a # e.g. `mydomain.com/#blog`

Comment: Try `#/blog` instead of `/#blog`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You start `Backbone.history` before you set up your listeners, which means they can't react to the initial routing that occurs on page load.

Move `Backbone.history.start();` out of your router definition, or at least after you setup the routes, and you should be good to go.

```
var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "blog": "blog",
        "*other": "defaultRoute"
    },

    blog: function() {},
    defaultRoute: function() {}                            
});

app.Router = new appRouter();


app.Router.on('route:defaultRoute', function() {
    console.log("Default Route");
});
app.Router.on('route:blog', function() {
    console.log("Blog Route");
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/k3Lcxwq2/